# What does the ? mean in an HTML absolute link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href, absolute

I am learning HTML on my own, and I ran across the following external link that assigns a different font to a tag in CSS:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I can't for the life of me find a definition of what the ? (question mark) does in this tag.  Could someone please address this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: For future reference, make sure you format your HTML in a code block properly (and also make sure to proofread your questions before posting), because if it isn't in a code block then it will get rendered as actual HTML instead of code.

Comment: Everything after `?` in a URL is the search *(or query)* part of the URL, which contains all `$_GET` properties.

Answer (score 6):

In a URL, the string following a `?` (question-mark) are [USVString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString) URI [Query String Parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

```
?prop=val&prop2=val2&prop3=val3
```

where the `&` acts as a *property=value* delimiter.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Usually used with GET requests to send additional data to the server in request for a specific response or action.

In the specific case of: `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster`

- `/css` is a just a *route* path, which only accepts Query parameters - or exits with 404
- `?family=Lobster` is a **property** and its corresponding **value**. The server detects  a Query param from a GET request it'll handle its properties and values. In this specific case returning a Content-Type text CSS.